# Не срабатывающий onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть код

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
          console.log('check');
          let subcategoryflag = '';
          $('.submenu__item a').on('click', function(event) {
            console.log('Inner check');
            subcategoryflag = event.target.innerHTML;
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'ajaxsubcategory1.php',
              data: {
                subcategoryflag: subcategoryflag
              },
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data) {
                console.log('check');
                console.log(data);
                $('.rightmenu').html(data.msg);
                $("div.FilterGroupNewDesign").each(function() {
                  let $div = $(this);
                  $div.parent().css("height", $div.height() /*+$div.next(".FilterGroupNewDesign__filter_show-all").height()+($div.parent()):nth-child(2).height()*/ );
                });
              }

              /*let checkboxElems = document.querySelectorAll('.FilterCheckBox__input');    */
            });
          });
          }
          )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="submenu__item"><a href="#">test link</a></div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('check');
    let subcategoryflag = '';
    $('.submenu__item a').on('click', function(event) {
      console.log('Inner check');
      subcategoryflag = event.target.innerHTML;
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajaxsubcategory1.php',
        data: {
          subcategoryflag: subcategoryflag
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          console.log('check');
          console.log(data);
          $('.rightmenu').html(data.msg);
          $("div.FilterGroupNewDesign").each(function() {
            let $div = $(this);
            $div.parent().css("height", $div.height() /*+$div.next(".FilterGroupNewDesign__filter_show-all").height()+($div.parent()):nth-child(2).height()*/ );
          });
        }

        /*let   checkboxElems = document.querySelectorAll('.FilterCheckBox__input');    */
      });
    });
  })
</script>
<div class="submenu__item"><a href="#">test link</a></div>
```

`console.log('check')` срабатывает, а внутрь

```js
$('.submenu__item a').on('click', function(event) {});
```

не заходит.
Подскажите как добиться обработки щелчка на пункте меню.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('ready');
  $('.submenu__item a').on('click', function(event) {
    console.log('click');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="submenu__item"><a href="#">test link</a></div>
```

Comment: а в чем разница между вашим и моим кодом?

Comment: @itspec891 Да, в чем разница? Разница в том, что я создал полный пример, где любой желающий может попробовать выполнить код и убедиться, что он работает.

Comment: я уточнил код. В чем ошибка кода до первой кнопки Выполнить код? Я по lineno и colno не понял где ошибка.

Comment: @itspec891 Ни в чем. Это тот же самый код, что и во втором фрагменте. Только Вы поместили кусок HTML-а в окно для скрипта.